# jQuery: Selecting adjacent tags unless separated by text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, traversal

I'm trying to find and combine adjacent `em` tags inside of paragraphs but it's proving more difficult than I expected.  Consider the following examples:

```
<p><em>Hello</em><em> World</em></p>

<p><em>Hello</em> <em>World</em></p>

<p><em>Hello</em> to the <em>World</em></p>
```

In the first and second examples above, I would expect `$("em + em")` to properly select the second `em` tag.  What I didn't expect was that it would also select cases like the third example where text appears between them.

Is there a way to detect the text between these tags and treat them differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I didn't expect was that it would also select cases like the third example where text appears between them.

The adjacent sibling combinator, `+`, doesn't take text into consideration. It will just select the immediately following sibling element.

You could filter all the adjacent `em` elements based on whether the previous sibling is an element or whitespace and exclude the element if text appears between the tags.

In the example below, the `em` in the third `p` isn't selected because the previous node is text.

```js
var $previousSiblings = $('em + em').filter(function () {
   var prev = this.previousSibling;
   return prev.nodeType === 1 ? true : !prev.nodeValue.trim();
});

$previousSiblings.css('color', '#f00');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><em>Hello</em><em> World</em></p>
<p><em>Hello</em> <em>World</em></p>
<p><em>Hello</em> to the <em>World</em></p>
```

---

If you want, you can also create a custom jQuery method.

For instance, here is a custom `.nextWithoutText()` method that will select the next element supplied if there isn't text in between the elements.

Usage: `$('em').nextWithoutText('em')`:

```js
$.fn.nextWithoutText = function(tag) {
  return $('+' + tag, this).filter(function() {
    var prev = this.previousSibling;
    return prev.nodeType === 1 ? true : !prev.nodeValue.trim();
  });
};

$('em').nextWithoutText('em').css('color', '#f00');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><em>Hello</em><em> World</em></p>
<p><em>Hello</em> <em>World</em></p>
<p><em>Hello</em> to the <em>World</em></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Josh.  Working at the node level did the trick.  I ended up scraping the `"em + em"` approach and just iterating over the elements checking the `nodeName` of the `nextSibling` and combining them if they matched.